# logback create log files inside folder having name as current date

Tags: java, logback, appender

In my current project i want to create log files date wise i.e. log files should reside inside
folder having name as date.
Also archiving should happen at that particular folder.

Current appender that i am using looks like this (it does archiving of log file based on size).

```
    <appender name="AUDITFILE"
    class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${PROJECT_HOME}\\projectname\\audits\\myproject.log</file>
    <append>true</append>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>${PROJECT_HOME}\\projectname\\audits\\myproject_%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.zip
        </fileNamePattern>
        <maxHistory>10</maxHistory>
        <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
            class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
            <maxFileSize>10KB</maxFileSize>

        </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%date %msg%n
        </pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As mentioned in the documentation for [fileNamePattern](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#tbrpFileNamePattern), you can specify multiple %d tokens so as put the date in the folder name of the archive filename:

```
<fileNamePattern>${PROJECT_HOME}\\projectname\\audits\\%d{yyyy-MM, aux}\\myproject_%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.zip</fileNamePattern>
```

Note that only one %d token can be primary, all other tokens must be marked as auxiliary by passing the 'aux' parameter.

But if you also want to put it in the file name of the non-archive filename, then you have two options:

1. use a `<timestamp />` element to set a variable which you use in the path.  But this timestamp will only be set once at startup, so it's good for batch runs but not for services.
2. Do like (1) above, but wrap the `<appender/>` and the `<timestamp />` with a `SiftingAppender`, which will enable the timestamp to be re-evaluated, if using version of logback >=1.0.12.  Not sure exactly how you'd want to configure the `SiftingAppender`.  But hopefully that will put you on the right track.