# how to create new folder every day and file in slf4j log

Tags: java, logging, log4j, slf4j

I am new to logging,
In my project we are starting to log the flow of project. from starting to end of the execution. we used simple write operations to log.

```
File,FileOutputStream
```

But i have seen tools like log4j,slf4j...etc
im in a confusion what to use and how to use.
I have seen many examples , but notthing matched my requirement .
which led to post a question here.

Q1) Which is the best log tool ? (we need to log nearly 1000 lines per day)
Q2) In the present project we are creating(with code) a new folder every day , and logging in that by using File,FileOutputStream,SimpleDateFormat...etc

Q3)Many configuration files give log file path hard coded.
example : org.slf4j.simpleLogger.logFile= /tmp/myapp.log
But in my project we need to create new folder every day.
like, path should be /tmp/20150419/myapp.log
20150419 is today's date.
and tomorrow log should be in 20150420
Is this possible ?

Please clarify , i will be thankful to you .

Comment: Use slf4j as the API and logback as the backend.  See http://logback.qos.ch/

Comment: https://gist.github.com/jcraane/5921329

Answer (score 0):

Q1 is opinion based, SO is not the place for such questions.

Q2 is not a question.

Q3 is not a question and not true. Every modern log framework provides means to define where you want to log, what to log and how to log it. They may have hard coded *defaults*, so you do not have to configure everything, but the ability is there. Case in point: [logback create log files inside folder having name as current date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16278720)

None of the requirements you mention are a challenge for today's logging frameworks, in fact they read very basic and simple.

As already mentioned by Thorbjørn, a good choice would be [logback](http://logback.qos.ch/), coupled with its interface SLF4J. The latter also provides means to switch to other logging implementations if you ever find logback to not be what you need. I suggest you familiarize yourself with logback and its capabilities via its documentation and then decide whether it fits your requirements.