# Getting Current Time For FixedWindowRollingPolicy in Play Framework Logging

Tags: playframework, logback

I want to hold up to 20 log files, where I rollback when a file reaches a certain size.
The catch is - when I archive a file I want to to have the current time in its' name.

Currently I use:

```
    <timestamp key="bySecond" datePattern="ddMMyyyy'-'HHmmss" timeReference="contextBirth"/>

    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${application.home}/logs/log.txt</file>
        <append>true</append>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${application.home}/logs/${bySecond}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
            <minIndex>1</minIndex>
            <maxIndex>30</maxIndex>
        </rollingPolicy>

        <triggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
            <maxFileSize>2KB</maxFileSize>
        </triggeringPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%date [%level] [%thread] from %logger  - %message%n%xException</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
```

But the problem here is the `bySecond` timestamp is evaluated only once at service start-up.

What I want is the current time for each rollover.
How can I achieve this?

BTW,
If i could get rid of the necessity to use the %i in the file name, it would be great!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16278720/logback-create-log-files-inside-folder-having-name-as-current-date

Comment: @MichałWolnicki It would work for TimeBasedRollingPolicy, but I use FixedWindowRollingPolicy, which doesn't allow the use of %d.

Comment: did you find an answer to this?

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem and the final solution I tried is extending the Rolling Policy Class. For example we want to change the name of the file which it is set by a method named `setFileNamePattern` in `FixedWindowRollingPolicy`. So the only thing you have to do is extending `FixedWindowRollingPolicy` by a custom class and overriding this method and calling the super one and append the current time to it. Finally, use this custom class name in `class` property of `rollingPolicy` in logback.xml.

```
import ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy;
import java.time.LocalDate;

public class MyRollingPolicy extends FixedWindowRollingPolicy {
    @Override
    public void setFileNamePattern(String fnp) {
        super.setFileNamePattern(fnp + LocalDate.now());
    }
}
```