# Logback does not clean up files properly

Tags: java, logging, logback, rollingfileappender, logback-classic

I am using Logback to manage logs on a server. I use the `RollingFileAppender` with a `TimeBasedRollingPolicy`:

```
<appender name="file-appender" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>/server/logs/error.log</file>
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
        <pattern>${defaultPattern}</pattern>
    </encoder>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <!-- hourly rollover -->
        <fileNamePattern>/server/logs/history/%d{yyyy-MM-dd,aux}/error.%d{yyyy-MM-dd_HH}.log.zip</fileNamePattern>
        <maxHistory>168</maxHistory> <!--7Days-->
        <totalSizeCap>1GB</totalSizeCap>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
        <level>ERROR</level>
    </filter>    
</appender>
```

I set `maxHistory` to 168 to keep the logs for seven days (one file per hour, 24 files a day = 168 files).

Looking in the `history` folder I'd expect to find a subdirecory for the last seven days and 24 zipped log files in each of them (besides the current and oldest).

But there are 76 folders going back about 4 month. For some days there is no folder and many folders do not contain zip files for each hour. But in total there are more than 1000 zip files in the `history` tree.

So there is some kind of clean-up, but it seems some files get cleaned up very late. What is wrong with my configuration? I am using version logback-classic-1.2.3.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [logback create log files inside folder having name as current date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16278720/logback-create-log-files-inside-folder-having-name-as-current-date)

Answer (score 1):

I have not used the rolling policy this way yet. I would implement it like this:

```
<fileNamePattern>/server/logs/history/error.%d{yyyy-MM-dd_HH}.log.zip</fileNamePattern>
```

See also [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16278720/logback-create-log-files-inside-folder-having-name-as-current-date)